# Watchdog for COM Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, com

i am developing a WCF application that does not adhere to the idea world of a true SOA in that it will have a few basic calls.

1) Start Process
2) Check if process is still running
3) Get results

This is all fine, but in order for execution to return from the 'start process' I am running my code in a separate thread using

`oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(wbrt.Calculate));`

The problem is it has been known (though rare) for the COM call to hog and sit at 50~100% cpu and consume lots of memory. There is nothing I can do to prevent this.

What I want to do is have a watchdog thread that will kill off the COM call if it is still running after some time (say 5 minutes).

Is there a best practice here? I have been reading the following blog:

http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2004/06/19/159985.aspx

in which he makes use of 'AutoResetEvent' and 'WaitOne' problem here is WaitOne is blocking so I'd have to have a thread within a thread.

Could I use a simple Thread Timer here? I saw that the timer will execute even if the thread has closed (i.e. finished ok) is that a problem if I use a flag or something to stop use of now dead objects?

Also I am creating my COM object using Activator.CreateInstance I tried Aborting the thread, but it does not kill the COM object and I have since read that Abort is bad.

My solution is to get the PID of the COM instance and simply kill, working on the assumption that if the timeout has hit diplomacy with the thread has gone out of the window.

Any thoughts well received!

Comment: You are going to have to host this COM object in its own process to have any chance at recovering from an abort.

Comment: Hi it the call that instantiates the COM is in its own thread, this then kicks off a call to an ole server which is registered and runs in its own process.

Comment: If the call gets stuck completely eating resources and memory, the way to kick it off without knowing tis internals is to terminate the thread. This idea however is really a crazy one as this does not effectively guarantee this surgery to be accurate (sync objects might be left in locked states, other threads running etc), so you'd be much better off putting the call onto separate process as suggested by Hans above. In this case terminating the process will force cleanup of resources and your parent app will get out of the lock gracefully, with HRESULTs instead of unreleased locks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is one ManualResetEvent with calling WaitAny() with a timeout value.

```
ManualResetEvent _evtActor = new ManualResetEvent();

public void Start()
{
    this._evtActor.Reset();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoStuff));

    int result = ManualResetEvent.WaitAny(
                    new WaitHandle[] { this._evtActor },
                    30 * 1000); // Wait 30sec

    if (result == ManualResetEvent.WaitTimeout)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timeout occurred!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    }
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff.");
    Thread.Sleep(45 * 1000); // sleep for 45sec;
    this._evtActor.Set();
}
```